# Plotting to a server(streaming rectangles) bin packing

Tags: python, matplotlib, bokeh

I'm trying to plot rectangles of different sizes on a server. I've figured out how to plot them all at once by using hold() and this is what i get

http://postimg.org/image/mh8z0z6nz/

here's the code i used plotting

```
import bokeh.plotting as bk
from bokeh.plotting import *

html_title="height=%r and width='%r'"%(height,width)
bk.output_file("maxrects.html",title="MAXRECTS")                #saving output to a file
bk.figure(plot_width=600,plot_height=600,title=html_title)      #plot specifics


bk.hold()                                                       
x_cor=[]
y_cor=[]
b_width=[]
b_height=[]


bk.rect([width/2],                                              #plotting the bin
    [int(height)/2],
    [width],
    [int(height)],fill_color="crimson")


bk.hold()                                                       #disables overwriting of         any previous glyph


for pr in maxbin.usedRectangles:                                
    b_x=pr.x+pr.width/2                                         #gets centre co-ordinates       of each used rectangle
    b_y=pr.y+pr.height/2
    x_cor.append(int(b_x))
    y_cor.append(int(b_y))
    b_width.append(int(pr.width))
    b_height.append(int(pr.height))

bk.rect(x_cor,                                                  #plotting function
    y_cor,
    b_width,
    b_height,fill_color="black")
 bk.save()                                                      #saves the output
 bk.show()
```

height and width are entered by the user and the bin(crimson) is initialized.
UsedRectangles contain all the black rectangles (x,y,width,height are the attributes of each rectangle object)

I want to send each object to a session one after the other.basically the plotting should be live(dynamic).the rectangles should be plotted one after the other.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

a workaround with matplotlib is also acceptable

Comment: I've removed the `matplotlib` tag, because this appears to be purely a `bokeh` question.  I also removed the `plot` and `session` tags, as they're too generic to help people find your question. If you think any of those are errors (or are looking for non-bokeh answers, as well), feel free to re-add the tags.

Comment: yeah,i just made some changes. matplotlib is also fine with me